# Could anyone help me with an Arduino sketch to control motor operation?

Tags: java, project, arduino-uno

I am making Arduino sketch to control motor operation according to water level in tank. The model is Arduino atMega 2560.

When lower button(water in tank is low) is LOW the led should become HIGH (motor will pump water) and when upper Button (water tank is filled) is HIGH led(motor) should get LOW.

This code not working:

```
const int lowerButtonPin = 2;
const int upperButtonPin = 3;
const int ledPin =  6;
int lowerButtonState = 0;
int upperButtonState = 0;  
/***************************setup****************************/

void setup() {  
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);  
    pinMode(lowerButtonPin, INPUT);
    pinMode(upperButtonPin, INPUT);
    digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);
}

/**********loop****************/

void loop() {
    lowerButtonState = digitalRead(lowerButtonPin);
    if(lowerButtonState==HIGH){
        digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH);
    } 
    upperButtonState = digitalRead(upperButtonPin);
    if(upperButtonState==HIGH){
        digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Please format your code and tell us how it is failing exactly.

Answer (score 1):

What I can tell is that when you're lower button is low, the led should become high. But here you've put lower button high, led high:

```
lowerButtonState = digitalRead(lowerButtonPin);

  if(lowerButtonState==HIGH){    
    digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH); 
  }
```

Try this:

```
lowerButtonState = digitalRead(lowerButtonPin);

  if(lowerButtonState==LOW){      // If lower button is low
    digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH);    // Set led high
  }
```